# How to merge 2 compositions with Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a string that I'm converting:

`"replace-me-correctly"` => `"Replace me correctly"`

my code using Ramda.js:

```
const _ = R; //converting Ramda.js to use _

const replaceTail = _.compose(_.replace(/-/g, ' '), _.tail);
const upperHead = _.compose(_.toUpper ,_.head);

const replaceMe = (str) => _.concat(upperHead(str) , replaceTail(str));

replaceMe("replace-me-correctly"); // "Replace me correctly"
```

What I'd like to know is if there is a cleaner more efficient way to combine `replaceTail` with `upperHead` so I only traverse the string once?

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/xawupe/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about traversing the string just once. Sounds difficult. I'll offer some different approaches for fun and insight though.

The monoid instance for function will concat each function by running them all with the given argument and concatting their results (they have to all return the same type to combine correctly). `replaceMe` is doing exactly that so we can use `mconcat` instead.

```
const { compose, head, tail, replace, toUpper } = require('ramda')
const { mconcat } = require('pointfree-fantasy')

// fun with monoids
const replaceTail = compose(replace(/-/g, ' '), tail)
const upperHead = compose(toUpper, head)
const replaceMe = mconcat([upperHead, replaceTail])

replaceMe("replace-me-correctly")
//=> "Replace me correctly"
```

That's a fun way to combine functions. I wasn't sure why the requirement was to grab the `tail` before the `replace`. Seems like the `replace` function could be updated to just replace any `-` past the starting char via regex. If that's the case we could inline the `replace`.

One more thing. The function instance of `dimap` from Profunctor is pretty neat and so are lenses. Using them together, we can convert the string to an array, then `toUpper` just the 0th index.

```
const { curry, compose, split, join, head, replace, toUpper } = require('ramda')
const { mconcat } = require('pointfree-fantasy')
const { makeLenses, over } = require('lenses')
const L = makeLenses([])

// fun with dimap
const dimap = curry((f, g, h) => compose(f,h,g))
const asChars = dimap(join(''), split(''))
const replaceMe = compose(replace(/-/g, ' '), asChars(over(L.num(0), toUpper)))

replaceMe("replace-me-correctly")
//=> "Replace me correctly"
```

Comment: Massive +1 the `mconcat` from your library is what I was looking for. Dimap looks fun will have to look further into that :)

Answer (score 4):

Brian's solutions are great.

Note that you can do something like `mconcat` in plain Ramda using `lift`:

```
const replaceMe = _.lift(_.concat)(upperHead, replaceTail)
```

Comment: ah cool I was searching through the docs for a while and couldn't find which operator to use thank you